# Using restful web service in place of soap without altering the user part of the request

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, soap

I have been trying to use restful webservice in place of legacy soap webservice without altering the user part of the request. I wanted to know whether this is achievable. Here is a sample code to demonstrate the issue :

Soap request :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:sch="https://www.flopradalley.com/xml/school">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <sch:StudentDetailsRequest>
     <sch:name>Arun</sch:name>
  </sch:StudentDetailsRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is my rest controller which should be able to respond to the request from SoapUI :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/restservice")
public class KenRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/details", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE
    )
    public StudentDetailsResponse execute(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        StudentDetailsRequest objectFromBody = null;// unmarshall the object from soap request and store it here
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();

            String lineStr = null;
            while ((lineStr = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(lineStr);
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* other code */
        return ---;
    }

}
```

I was only able to get the soap request as text and store it in a string buffer. I know this isn't remotely the way it should be done if it is possible to handle soap requests using rest. I know that rest is an archicture and is a whole lot difference from soap and it looks like there is no direct way to handle soap requests using rest at the least.

Apart from this sample code, I should be able to extract the SoapMessage, MessageContext, Soapheader, SoapBody from the request. That brings me to the original question on whether it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the change into a REST API I highly recommend to not keep thinging in some of the webservice logic.

The SOAP protocol is a method to pass information that contains both the answer and the metadata of the call.

In rest you obtain the answer in the body of the responses and the most used format is json. You can directly pass as a parameter in the method the object that is going to be parsed into the java object by Spring REST (it uses Jackson library to parse in reality).

```
    @RestController
public class KenRestController {

    @GetMapping("/restService/details/{studentId}") // post is for saving an elelement
    public StudentDetailsResponse getDetails(@PathVariable("studentId") Integer studentId) {
        // you get the details and parse it to the object you want to return
        return studentService.getStudentById(studentId);
    }

    // example of response class
    private class StudentDetailsResponse implements Serializable{

        // pojo class
    }
}
```

Please don't hesitate to make any questions about that.

Comment: I need to handle a soap request using Rest. I think it is impossible.

Comment: they are two different approaches totally different in their basis. My recomendation, use webservices or REST not a mix.